Tenses change the meaning
A) I had had a car before she arrived vs I had a car before she arrived
B) I had been in bed when you arrived vs I was in bed when you arrived
All these sentences are correct, but those with the perfect tense strongly indicate that I no longer had that car or was in bed after she arrived whereas sentences written with the simple tense don't indicate anything like that. We can't be sure if it was the case after she arrived or not.  Is that true that perfect tenses may imply that something is no longer true like I presented here. The same applies to futre perfect and future simple tenses.

Hello again! Like the other question you posted, the only question here is "am i right?" which is basically proof-reading. It's not a question about learning English. I went into a bit more detail in my other comment about how you could maybe make a suitable question.

@Astralbee why do you think so? I found the rule regarding how the meaning changes depending on the tense. I want to check if it is really like that. I'm not asking to just check my mistakes. It is a question about the rule and I'm trying to see if I understand that rule correctly

There's one question mark in your post. "Am I right?" There are only two possible answers to that - yes, and no. Think about future readers of this website - what would they learn from this question if it were answered? Nothing, unless they'd constructed the exact same example as you, and even then they'd only know it was right, not why it was right. Is there a reason why you think you are wrong? Perhaps if you expanded on that reason it might lead to a suitable question, but at the moment it isn't.

Why? Simply because I am not a native speaker hahah.  How about you answer yes or no because that's what I need and I delete that question?

before/after + simple past.
As both sentences are different let's first consider  OP's sentence A

A)Ihad had a car before she arrived vs I had a car before she arrived.

Both the sentences are different. In the first sentence "had" is past tense of "have" which means to own something.
,
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

We use before as a subordinating conjunction. We commonly use before with the past simple tense. It suggests that the second event happened soon after the first one.

So these two sentences have the same meaning.
The train had left when we reached the station.
The train left before we reached the station.
Ii. Difference between Present Perfect and Simple Past.
Now let's consider sentence B.

B) I had been in bed when you arrived vs I was in bed when you arrived

"I had been in bed when you arrived"  implies that I was already in bed for some time before you arrived.
The Present Perfect tense ("had been") emphasizes the duration of being in bed before your arrival, suggesting that it was an ongoing state that started before you came.

I was already in bed for some time before you arrived (not just at the moment of arrival)

"I was in bed when you arrived" simply states that I was in bed at the exact moment of your arrival. It doesn't imply anything about how long I was in bed before that moment or whether I was already asleep.
Edit.
The sentence "I had been in bed when you arrived" can be interpreted in two ways:

I was already in bed before you arrived, and I might still be in bed when you arrived (emphasis on the duration leading up to your arrival).
I was in bed before you arrived, but I might not be in bed anymore (implication of a completed action).

The second interpretation is similar to "He has been to China", which implies that he is no longer in China.
If you want to clearly indicate that you were no longer in bed when the person arrived, you could use a different sentence, like "I had been in bed before you arrived" or "I was already out of bed when you arrived".
"I had gone to bed, when you arrived." clearly indicates that I went to bed before you arrived and still in bed when you arrived.

So both really have the same meaning, correct?  What about this? I will in bed before you come and I will have been in bed before you come. Is there a difference?

What if I change it to arrive?

@Adam Future tenses are used sparingly as compared to Present and past tense. We use the future perfect simple (will/won't have + past participle) to talk about something that will be completed before a specific time in the future. The guests are coming at 8 p.m. I'll have finished cooking by then. On 9 October we'll have been married for 50 years.
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/future-continuous-future-perfect#:~:text=We%20use%20the%20future%20perfect,been%20married%20for%2050%20years.

@Adam Consider the following:
Husband: I will be home by 11 pm today. Wife: By the time you arrive, I will have gone to bed. (Future Perfect) OR "By the time you arrive, I will have been sleeping for 2 hours.(Future Perfect Continuous).

"By the time you arrive, I will have been in bed" doesn't it imply that she won't in that bed anymore once the husband is back?

Are you a native speaker? My teacher told me something different that she wasn' there in bed anymore byt my teacher isn't a native. Are you sure about your statements?

@Adam  My original sentence was : The sentence "By the time you arrive, I will have gone to bed" actually implies the opposite: that I will still be in bed when you arrive. This sentence suggests that I will be in bed before your arrival and will still be in bed when you arrive.

Not 'been" but gone.. been may imply what your teacher told. He has been to China. means he is no longer in China'.

@Adam "I had gone to bed, when you arrived." clearly indicates that you I went to bed before you arrived and still in bed when you arrived.. "I had been in bed" in your case can be interpreted in different ways.


I had had a car before she arrived.

In this example, there's no indication in the first version that I no longer had a car after her arrival; the two versions have the same meaning.
This applies also to the in bed example.
When the sequence of events is clear, the past perfect is unnecessary; if used, it is just there; it doesn't hint that an earlier state would end after a subsequent event has occurred.
Substituting before with until would give that meaning:

I had had a car until she arrived.


So both really have the same meaning, correct? What about this? I will in bed before you come and I will have been in bed before you come. Is there a difference?

Since you're asking about the tenses in general I'm not going to use your  example sentences.
I owned a car before we moved into the city can have these intended meanings:

I used to own a car (i.e. but sold  it or had it stolen or forgot where I parked it) before we moved into the city.


I have owned the car I own now since before we moved into the city.

I had owned a car before we moved into the city cannot have the intended meaning:

I have owned the car I own now  since before we moved into the city.


simply  when I say "I had been drunk when you came" or "I will have have a car before you arrive"  both examples imply that once that person arrived I was already sober and without car hah. Correct?

@Adam I had been drunk when you came is not idiomatic English;  I don't know what it means.  Please stop using "when you came"  and "when she came" as they are ambiguous with respect to time; they could be taken as "visited" or "arrived".  It's very tiresome to see you using these crude utterances again and again when trying to ascertain the nuanced differences of verb tenses.

because my sentence "I had been drunk when you arrived" implies I wasn't drunk anymore once someone came you it view as unidiomatic. Correct? It is just strange to say something like that yes?

could you comment on that question as well? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/356498/perfect-tenses-and-the-use

@Adam I think you haven't read my comment above? In by-you-adduced contexts it is all about The Present Perfect Inclusive. With durative verbs such as "to be, to have, to live, to teach, to drink" or with situations the implications of Pr.Perf. are INCLUSIVE. I.e. saying "I had been drunk when you arrived" you clue someone up that you WERE being drunk at his/her dropping in and, perhaps, was found knocking around on the floor.

@Eugene thank you for that comment. Could you  check my other question?https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/356498/perfect-tenses-and-the-use

@Adam   Here's what we know: The utterance is made after the person's arrival. At some point prior to their arrival, whether imediately before their arrival or years before their arrival,  you were drunk. before is indefinite with respect to recency.We cannot tell whether you are explaining the then fresh vomit on your shirt or  asserting that you had been drunk at some earlier point in your life, perhaps when you drank a glass of brandy once when your parents left you at home alone.  And so we cannot know if you were still inebriated when they arrived.

And that's why we say in English things like "right before, immediately before, some time before, a few minutes, days, hours, weeks, months, years, before,  long before, decades before, ages before".

@TimR I found an abstruse grammar combination on Ngram that I coudn't take in from a grammatical point (I guess I could have sussed it up in the deapth of my consciousness, nevertheless). Here it is (it's from some storm data bulletin of July 1993). "As of Friday (7/16/93) the backwater from the Mississippi in the Bear Creek Bottoms area had chased more than 2000 people from their homes. By Monday (7-19-93) the flood HAS driven 400 residents from their homes... Sunday (7-25-93) a levee near Hannibal broke flooding 9000 acres...". I don't grip why is it Pr.Perf. after "By Monday (7-19-93).."

which is the marker of past time?

@Eugene When a person presents timeline data to an audience (e.g. a commentator on the news discussing a chart or a radio announcer or spokesperson reading from a timeline of events, etc) their first statement will often be from the perspective of speaker-audience NOW, to orient the audience. And so we find the past perfect for 7/16/93, something that happened before some other past event. But then the presenter will often switch back and forth between historical present (chart time) and the past, mixing time contexts.  And so we find present perfect for 7/19 and then past for 7/25.

@Eugene You'll often hear commentators describing a chart on TV say things like ".... and then the unemployment rate falls in 2011 only to rise again in 2012 and 2013.  But then it fell once again in 2014."

@TimR Thank you very much. Most native speakers have not once gotten after me asserting that The Present Perfect is impossible with the markers of past time, notwithstanding there being multiple examples, where using PR.Perf was well vindicated. "From 1954 up to 1965, approximately sixty apartment buildings, totalling some 1500 dwelling units, have been completed", "Well, we have done in the past, haven't we?", Did he remind of Major Smith or Bertie Jones or someone you've known years ago", "We have all been young once, we have all felt the same".

There can also be interesting combinations of Pr.Perf. and PastPerf and Past simple to tumble against. "He's been here once or twice, while his wife was on holiday", "He has met her several times but he has never told his wife that he had met her", "Have you ever spoken to her after she had had one of her fits?"

@Eugene Re the 1954-1965 utterance, if it appeared in a summary of data presented in a chart showing the history of multi-unit residential development in a particular city, it could well be historical present, and no explicit intra-utterance time marker is necessary in such cases.  Well, we have done in the past, haven't we? is clearly a rejoinder, which can borrow the time context from what it's replying to. The other sentences seem explainable. One would have to know the conversational context, since what has just been said by another person can have bearing on grammaticality of the reply.

@Eugene Consider this conversation: Have you ever eaten scallops? --Yes, I've eaten them before.  There is relevance to the present. That is perfectly grammatical. Or this one: The city can't just evict people from their homes because a developer wants to build a casino!  --Well, you've done so in the past, haven't you?  There, the relevancy of the past action to the present situation is important:  "in the past" isn't intended in that utterance to confine the action to the past but to point out a precedent for the (desired) present eviction. The semantics are key.

@TimR Splendid!

@TimR I have noticed that I garbled a word order which slants my real implication.There ought to have been: "Most native speakers have gotten after me not once, asserting that The Present Perfect is impossible with the markers of past time...

@Eugene Well, this native speaker will tell you that the present perfect cannot be used with time adjuncts in the clause that confine the action to the past.  The mere presence of a time marker that has something to do with the past doesn't rule out the possibility that there is some relevance to the present. An example I gave you was the sentence where the intended involvement of a past action was that it served as precedent for a present situation. The past action is therefore linked to the present, not confined to the past.

"Haven't you done so years ago" is ungrammatical as is "Haven't you done so before then?" whereas "Haven't you done so before*?" is OK when "before" means "before now".

@TimR Clean and simple conception!

In each example both variations have the same meaning and will be understood to mean the same by many English speakers.

So both really have the same meaning, correct? What about this? I will in bed before you come and I will have been in bed before you come. Is there a difference?

@Adam [why do you sturdily keep making it out without "be", i.e "I will {be} in bed", unless "will" is a self-contained verb preserving its strong volitional meaning] You may be muddling around the implication of Pr.Perf. because it does realy infer that the situation continues through the unspecified time leading up to the present (with durable verbs the Pr.Perf. can be put in instead of Pr.Per.Cont.). In your #1 example Pr.Perf strongly indicates that you still had the car and would possess it further. If it had been about not having it when she arrived you shoud've brought in a modifier

of frequency: "I had had a car for three times before she arrived." This reading can allude to having no car at the moment of her arrival. It can be the situation also with an adverbial modifier of time or smth. "I had had a car long before she arrived 60 years after".
