Perfect tenses and the use
The way to express that we will have done something for some time  till a point in time is to use future perfect and say for instance
I will have been working/will have worked there for 2 years on Monday
My question is: does past perfect work the same way but in the past?
I had been doing working /had worked there for 2 years on Monday.

Hi there. To be accepted on this site, a question has to be on a specific point of learning English. Proof-reading is off-topic, so unfortunately your question "am i right?" isn't suitable. It sounds like you've done your research - if there was a specific reason why you didn't trust what you found (eg two things you found conflicted) then maybe that could form the basis of a valid question.

"I am passionate about helping people who genuinely appreciate it."

@Adam It can also go off well in certain contexts with some modals: "I guess he would/could have had a car (have worked=have been working) for two years by the time/when she arrived a year ago".

@Eugene do you find my sentence with past perfect correct?

@Adam "As of/by last Monday I had been working /had worked there for 2 years". "On Monday it was the date when I had been working /had worked there for 2 years"

@TimR could you comment on my question?

OP's query:

My question is: does past perfect work the same way but in the past?
I had been doing working /had worked there for 2 years on Monday.

Please note that in this instance, the Past Perfect Continuous is inappropriate as it works better when  the completion point is an event rather than a set day or date.  Some grammar text books may use Past Perfect in this way.
You don't need to use these tenses if you can convey the same idea in the Simple Past tense.
On Monday, I completed my second year of employment there.
Past perfect tense and Past Perfect Continuous tense can be used in the following manner(both have same meaning):
My aunt had been living in London for fifteen years when she died.
My aunt had lived in London for fifteen years when she died.
